# Merge project modules created on different PC

Tags: visual-studio

We are working on a VB project. There are 3 members in my team. They are developing different-different module of project on their PC.

I wan to merge their developed modules/forms in my project solution.

Anyone please help me that how to merge their developed modules/forms in my project solution.
..

Please help...

Comment: Are you talking about modern VB.NET or the old VB6 or (Excel) VBA?

Comment: I'm looking for both? Modern Visual studio 2015 and visual studio 6.0 enterprise..

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider for both Visual Studio 2015 and the even older Visual Studio 6 when working with multiple users:

- Sharing additions and changes of the class/module files
- Updating the project file to include newly added files

The second step is needed because new files aren't added to the project automatically (unlike newer versions of Visual Studio).

You can manually add the new files to the project by right-clicking the project in the Project Explorer (or Solution Explorer in VS2015). Then select "Add File" or "Add -> Existing Item..." to add the file to your project (these may be named a bit different, I'm not using these two versions at the moment).

---

As a side note, while it is certainly possible to share files by using the above method, it might be worth considering a proper Version Control System to help collaboration between you and your co-workers.

Setting up [Git](https://git-scm.com/) for example is reasonably easy and it scales well to any team and project size (and their are many viable alternatives too). These systems automate the process of sharing changes between users, including the project file itself.

Most of these also integrate into Visual Studio 2015, making the whole process smoother.
There is no integration for Visual Studio 6, but you can just version control the project files directly as directory. This can be done by using console commands, or you can use one of many Git desktop clients...

In fact, we've sucessfully managed multiple VB6 projects using Git in the past and it worked reasonably well (as good as working with VB6 ever gets, really).